# GTK+ 2.0 dynamic array

Tags: c, gtk

I am new to GTK+ and am writing in C using Eclipse. I have a couple of questions, if anyone can help I'll be more than thankful.

1. I need to make a dynamic array of widgets (number of widgets can vary, like buttons or images). How can I achieve this?
2. I am using table to align all, is it a good practice? I want all of the widgets to align vertically, 4 at a row;
3. I am using Linux and I need to find all of the applications from 
   application folder, use the "Icon" as an image and on click, execute the application. how can I do this using C with GTK+?
4. Is there any way of making an image widget clickable?

My code look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    GtkWidget *window, *table, *FileDialog, *button, *vbox, *vbox_2, *vbox_3, *vbox_4, *image, *label,
    *label_2, *label_3, *label_4, *image_2, *image_3, *image_4, *ebox;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    table = gtk_table_new(1,1,0);
    button = gtk_button_new();
    label = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), "<b>Files</b>");
    label_2 = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label_2), "<b>Music</b>");
    label_3 = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label_3), "<b>Pictures</b>");
    label_4 = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label_4), "<b>Videos</b>");

    ebox = gtk_event_box_new();
    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    vbox_2 = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    vbox_3 = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    vbox_4 = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/demo/Pictures/Files.png");
    image_2 = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/demo/Pictures/Music.png");
    image_3 = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/demo/Pictures/Pictures.png");
    image_4 = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/demo/Pictures/Videos.png");


    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), image, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox_2), image_2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox_3), image_3, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox_4), image_4, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox_2), label_2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox_3), label_3, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox_4), label_4, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), vbox, 1,2,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 40, 0);
    gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), vbox_2, 2,3,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 40, 0);
    gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), vbox_3, 3,4,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 40, 0);
    gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), vbox_4, 4,5,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 40, 0);


    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 1024, 700);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), ebox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(ebox), table);
    g_signal_connect(GTK_WIDGET(ebox), "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(open_folder), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 75);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return(0);
}
```

how can I use the event box for each image seperatly?

and how can I work with better practice here?

please, i am getting desperate!

p.s.

when I try to open file chooser dialog on click of event box it cruses also.

Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_window_set_transient_for: assertion 'parent == NULL || GTK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, GTK+ 2 will not be supported soon. Please consider writing in GTK+ 3, and [migrating current projects to GTK+ 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html).

Now, to answer your questions:

1. You can declare a pointer of type `GtkWidget **`, and use standard `malloc()` and `realloc()` techniques. This should be the same as dynamic arrays of any other types. Alternatively, you may also use a linked list. GTK+ depends on GLib, so you can use [`GList`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html) without using other libraries.
2. No, it is not. As written in the GTK+ 3 manual:

   > GtkTable has been deprecated. Use [GtkGrid](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.5/GtkGrid.html) instead. It provides the same capabilities as GtkTable for arranging widgets in a rectangular grid, but does support height-for-width geometry management.

   So unless you definitely must write in GTK+ 2, please use GTK+ 3 and GtkGrid.
3. This is probably too broad to answer, but I can give you some general directions. I assume you already have the path to a directory containing the applications. You can then use the file utilities provided by GLib, such as using [`g_dir_open()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-dir-open) to open the directory and using related functions to loop through each file. As for finding out the icon of an application, I think this may be platform-dependent. For example, in Ubuntu, application .desktop files are stored in `/usr/share/applications`. You can parse each file to find the `Icon=` line and find the corresponding icon *somewhere* (depending on your theme) in `/usr/share/icons`.
4. Connect to the [button-press-event signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) or the [button-release-event signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-release-event), depending on what you need. [Read more about signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/x159.html) if you don't know what they are or how to use them.

Comment: @user4702146 You don't even need the event box. Just use the "button-press-event" on each individual image widget. You can use the `user-data` argument of the function to pass identifiers for each widget so that the callback will know which image is pressed. As for the warning you get, please ask a new question with the relevant code present. How do you expect me to know what's wrong if you don't even tell me how you "try to open the file chooser dialog"?

Comment: how do I write the call back? it doesn't to work on the image.

Comment: @user4702146 If you are having specific coding trouble implementing the callback, ask a new question, showing relevant code and *be specific*. Not just "How do I do it?", but "I've done this but it doesn't work. I want this to happen but that happened instead. How do I fix it?". If you just want general directions, I can't explain more than I did in the previous comment.

Comment: posted another question, with the call back code :)